# WP7 how to use toolkit TransitionFrame?

Tags: windows-phone-7, transition

I've downloaded the most recent Windows.Phone.Controls.Toolkit and in the app.xaml.cs changed

```
RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
```

to

```
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
```

I expected some change in the transition between pages, but nothing happened at all.

Do I need to do something more to achieve more interesting transitions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add reference `xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`

and try Turnstile effect by adding:

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>                
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

to each page you want to have transition effect.

Or you can try other effects such as: Slide, Swivel, Rotate and Roll.

Comment: Oh, I absolutely missed that I'd need to add something to every page. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

For posterity:

If you don't want to have to write all that XAML for every page, create a helper class and apply the transitions in your page's constructor.

**Transitions.cs**

```
public class Transitions {

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the Turnstile transition for this UIElement
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element"></param>
    public static void UseTurnstileTransition(UIElement element)
    {
        TransitionService.SetNavigationInTransition(element,
            new NavigationInTransition() {
                Backward = new TurnstileTransition() {
                    Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.BackwardIn
                },
                Forward = new TurnstileTransition() {
                    Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.ForwardIn
                }
            }
        );

        TransitionService.SetNavigationOutTransition(element,
            new NavigationOutTransition() {
                Backward = new TurnstileTransition() {
                    Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.BackwardOut
                },
                Forward = new TurnstileTransition() {
                    Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.ForwardOut
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**ExamplePage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ExamplePage : PhoneApplicationPage {
    public ExamplePage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        Transitions.UseTurnstileTransition(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat, +1 — though in general I prefer to do it using a style so that it's explicit even when looking at the XAML. I've added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note to expand on @subkamran's answer. Instead of a helper class, you can also use a style:

```
<Style x:Key="TransitionPageStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
    <Setter Property="toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition">
        <Setter.Value>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
                <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                    <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
                </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                    <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
                </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition">
        <Setter.Value>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
                <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                    <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
                </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                    <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
                </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have specified that you want to use the TransitionFrame you then need to tell the app what sort of Transitions you want coming into and going out of the page, here is some typical XAML that I use:

first register the namespace in the header of the page:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

then set the transitions

```
  <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeIn" />
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
```

You can try the different transition types to find the one that best fits in with your application.

HTH,
Rupert.